# Django. Передача параметров из шаблона c формой в представление и запись в БД

Tags: django, python-3.x

Нужно организовать передачу в функцию данных одного из полей формы(для записи в БД) и дополнительных элементов(присутствуют на странице шаблона) user.id, status.id . Сейчас в функцию передается только product.id, при добавлении дополнительных элементов в , при переходе на страницу с формой выдает:

> Reverse for 'zakaz' with arguments '(1, 2)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/zakaz/$']

как настроить передачу нужных параметров в представление и последующую запись их в БД в нужные столбцы?

models.py

```
class Zakaz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey("product", Product)
    status = models.ForeignKey("status", Status)
    suggestions = models.TextField("пожелания", max_length=1000)
```

forms.py

```
class ZakazForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Zakaz
        fields = ['suggestions']
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    form = ZakazForm
    context = {'product': product, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'main/detail.html', context)

def zakaz(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ZakazForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            // Запись всего в БД
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
            form = ZakazForm
            context = {'product': product, 'form': form}
            return render(request, 'main/detail.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/zakaz/$', views.zakaz, name="zakaz"),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name="thanks"),
]
```

detail.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'main:zakaz' product.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <dt>{{ field.label_tag }}</dt>
            <dd class="clearfix">
                {{ form }}
            </dd>
        <input type="submit" value="Заказать" / class="clearfix">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать в url именованный аргумент:

```
{% url 'main:zakaz' pk=product.id %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы показали ошибку, но не показали `views.py` при котором гененируется ошибка. Судя по ошибке, Вы сюда `{% url 'main:zakaz' product.id %}` добавляете какой-то лишний параметр